# cygwin c sem_init

Tags: c, cygwin, semaphore

```
if((sem_init(sem, 1, 1)) == 1) perror("error initiating sem");
```

If I include this line of code my program simply starts and exits. I just started learning how to use semaphores. I'm using cygwin and when this line is commented out the printf's ABOVE this print to console but when include this, nothing happens.

I did the following to get cygserver going-

```
CYGWIN=server
ran /bin/cygserver-config
ran /usr/sbin/cygserver
```

for the config it said the cygserver is already running
And for the sygserver it saids-

```
initailaizing complete
failed to created named pipe: is the daemon already running?
fatal error on IPC transport: closing down
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Read a [manual page](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/sem_init.html) and check the return value.

Comment: Sorry, new to stackoverflow. Didn't know where the 'accept' was. I've read the man page for sem_init().
Sorry just noticed the return value '1' should be '-1' but that changed nothing. I put '\n' after my 'printf' and for some reason it prints now. It's progressing...

Comment: It wasn't printing because when stdout is a terminal, printf buffers its output into memory and only flushes its buffers when either a newline is printed, its buffer becomes full, or you explicitly flush it with `fflush(3)`.  If your program crashes before the buffer gets flushed, the buffered output never appears.  When debugging a crash issue, you should always be sure to flush your buffers to make sure it's crashing where you think it's crashing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out what was wrong. I was using data(struct) = shmat() before I was assigning any memory to data. That for some reason was stopping my 'printf' from working.